How do I use a function to create a button in Tkinter?
In line 21, I'm trying to create a button that will execute the editUser() function. Instead, the button does nothing, and the editUser() function is executed for all existing users whenever I click the "confirm" button in the addUser window. What am I doing wrong?
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

users = []

class User:
    def __init__(self, name, points):
        self.n = name
        self.p = points

main = Tk()
main.title("Main")

def addUser():
    global users
    addUserWindow = Tk()
    addUserWindow.title("Add User")
    def confirm():
        global users
        users.append(User(nameentry.get(),0))
        newUser = Button(main, text = users[len(users)-1].n, command = editUser(len(users)-1))
        newUserPoints = Label(main, text = users[len(users)-1].p)
        newUser.grid(column = 0, row = len(users)+1)
        newUserPoints.grid(column = 1, row = len(users)+1)
        addUserWindow.destroy()
    name = Label(addUserWindow, text="Name: ")
    newname = StringVar()
    nameentry = Entry(addUserWindow, width = 8, textvariable = newname)
    upd = Button(addUserWindow, text = "add", command = confirm)
    name.grid(column = 0, row = 0)
    nameentry.grid(column = 1, row = 0)
    upd.grid(column = 1, row = 1)

def editUser(x):
    editUserWindow = Tk()
    editUserWindow.title("Edit User")
    frame = Frame(editUserWindow)
    frame.grid(column=0,row=0)
    user = Label(frame, text= users[x].n)
    points = Label(frame, text= users[x].p)
    userentry = Entry(frame)
    pointsentry = Entry(frame)
    def confirm():
        global users
        users[x].n = userentry.get()
        users[x].p = pointsentry.get()
        editUserWindow.destroy()
    confirmButton = Button(frame, text = "confirm", command = confirm)
    user.grid(column = 0, row = 0)
    points.grid(column = 0, row = 1)
    userentry.grid(column = 1, row = 0)
    pointsentry.grid(column = 1, row = 1)
    confirmButton.grid(column = 2, row = 1)

addUserButton = Button(main, text = 'add user', command = addUser)
addUserButton.grid(column = 1, row = 1)

main.mainloop()


At a glance, this needs to be changed to a lamda: command = editUser(len(users)-1) should be command = lambda: editUser(len(users)-1). You need to do this in order to call a function with arguments as a command - otherwise, as written, editUser(len(users)-1) is called immediately when the newUser button is created.

Does this answer your question? How to pass arguments to a Button command in Tkinter?

@Christian Hodges. Your code is working. I change TK() to editUserWindow = Toplevel() Not using lambda

instead of users[len(users)-1] you can do users[-1]

inside ( ) don't use spaces around =. See more PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code
